# How to solve Core Data error in AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I created an application with Core Data. In the AppDelegate I have this code:

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        /*
         The persistent container for the application. This implementation
         creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
         application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
         error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
        */
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Teste")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

                /*
                 Typical reasons for an error here include:
                 * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                 * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                 * The device is out of space.
                 * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                 Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                 */
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()
```

I'd like to remove the fatalError and know how the typical reasons for an error can occurs that they talk about?

Answer (score 0):

So you can remove or comment out the `fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")` line of code. If you read the first line in the comments "Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately", it tells us that we are meant to use our own implementation, the `fatalError()` method is for your development purposes to be notified in debug that something went awry.

Typically caused by a misconfiguration of your project, or heaven forbid a failure to migrate between versions. In these situations you would hopefully have caught and fixed these issues before your project goes live, but if the error occurred because the device has run out of storage space or a permissions issue it would be best just to observe this error and whenever it occurs inform the user through an alert.